# Extracting infromation from table on Web Page using perl

Tags: perl

I am very new to perl and need some help with extracting a table from a web page. I was able to figure out how to get the page to print with perl today. Now I just need to only extract the information in the table which states the temperature.
My current code is:

```
# perl
use strict;
# use LWP::Simple;
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent;
$ua->timeout(120);
my $url='http://MyTempSite/';
my $request = new HTTP::Request('GET', $url);
my $response = $ua->request($request);
my $content = $response->content();
print $content;
```

I am trying to get the temperature readings from this html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"><html><body    bgcolor="#C0C0C0" text="#000000" vlink="#800080" link="#0000FF"><P><h1>TempTrax Digital Thermometer</h1><BR><table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0><TR><TD>Model:</TD><TD width=10 rowspan=7><BR></TD><TD>E4</TD><TR><TD>Manufacturer:</TD><TD>Sensatronics</TD> </TR><TR><TD>Website:</TD><TD><a href="http://www.sensatronics.com">http://www.sensatronics.com</a></TD></TR><TR><TD>Firmware Version:</TD><TD>1.2</TD></TR><TR><TD>Release Date:</TD><TD>December 16, 2003</TD></TR><TR><TD>Serial Number:</TD><TD>EA8E6L0T121</TD></TR><TR><TD>Unit name:</TD><TD>LiveTempMonitor</TD></TR></TABLE><P><h3>Current temperature readings:</h3><p><table><TR><TD width=200>Probe1:</TD><TD> 75.1</TD></TR>
<TR><TD width=200>Probe2:</TD><TD>-99.9</TD></TR>
<TR><TD width=200>Probe3:</TD><TD>-99.9</TD></TR>
<TR><TD width=200>Probe4:</TD><TD>-99.9</TD></TR>
</table></body></html>
```

How should I go about getting only the information in the "Current temperature readings" table to be pulled? Thank you all ahead of time for taking a look at this.

Comment: [HTML::TableExtract](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::TableExtract), [HTML::TableParser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::TableParser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML qw( );

my $html = $response->decoded_content( charset => 'none' );
my $doc  = XML::LibXML->load_html( string => $html );
my $root = $doc->documentElement();
my @readings =
   map $_->textContent(),
    $root->findnodes(
       '//table[ position() = 2 ]/tr/td[ position() = 2 ]'
    );

say for @readings;
```